# how to hide password with ********* on swagger ui with flask_restplus in python

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Hi Below is my running code , can be accessed with below URL:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/documentation

```
from flask import Flask, Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

app = Flask(__name__)
blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(blueprint, doc='/documentation') #,doc=False

app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

app.config['SWAGGER_UI_JSONEDITOR'] = True

login_details = api.model('LoginModel',{'user_name' : fields.String('The Username.'),'pass_word' : fields.String('The password.'),})
# pass_word = api.model('Pwd', {'pass_word' : fields.String('The password.')})
credentials = []
python = {'user_name' : '1234','pwd':'23213413'}
credentials.append(python)

@api.route('/login')
class Language(Resource):

    @api.marshal_with(login_details, envelope='the_data',mask='pass_word')
    def get(self):
        return credentials

    @api.expect(login_details)
    @api.marshal_with(login_details, envelope='the_data',mask='pass_word')
    def post(self):
        login_details = api.payload
        print(login_details)
        login_details['id'] = len(credentials) + 1

        credentials.append(login_details)
        return {'result' : 'credentials added'}, 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Can you please tell what should i do to to hide the password with ***** when i entering on the swagger UI , and value should be passed to the argument correctly.

Comment: I think you need to question the design since you need to type a password in swagger-ui, which is a development tool. 
By right, you type a password in a User Interface (which you build for purpose-fit). Swagger-ui is a development/testing tool.

Answer (score 5):

According to [flask-restful documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#models) about Models, you can see at the beginning that the [`fields.Raw`](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.fields.Raw) class can take a [`format` parameter](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.fields.Raw.format) :

It can:

> modify how the value of existing object keys should be presented

So you can use this `format` parameter with the value `'password'`, as documented in the [Swagger documentation about data types](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/) under the "String" section :

> An optional format modifier serves as a hint at the contents and format of the string. OpenAPI defines the following built-in string formats:
>
> [...]
>
> password – a hint to UIs to mask the input

So you COULD use this `format='password'` like so in your field definition:

```
pass_word = fields.String('The password.', format='password')
```

But the problem is that you are using the `expect` decorator, with standard `Model` definition, which does not allow you to easily customize your request parser. I would recommend to use [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/) to be able to have better control of your object serialization.

Answer (score 0):

For people in the future, prefer to use Flask_RestX (instead of discontinued flask_restplus), if the `format=password` wont work, you can use `reqparse` with password schema type:

```py
Password = fields.String()
Password.__schema_format__ = "password"
parser.add_argument('pass', type=Password(), location='files')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take, for example, the email object in flask-restx.inputs and create your own password object.

```
class password(object):
    def __call__(self, value):
        return value

    @property
    def __schema__(self):
        return {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "password",
        }

parser.add_argument(
    'password',
    type=password(),
    location='form',
)
```